# Gradle daemon not reused when running in debug mode (in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-daemon

I created new Java project in IntelliJ IDEA with gradle (and added one class which prints hello world). Then I try to run project both in *debug* and *non-debug* modes.

When I first time run in *non-debug mode*, IntelliJ prints that new daemon was started, and on subsequent launches this daemon is reused.

But when I run in *debug mode*, IntelliJ prints that new daemon was started **each time** (both first one, and subsequent ones).

How can I make IntelliJ to reuse gradle daemon when running in *debug mode*?

(I have gradle 5.2.1 and IntelliJ 2019.3.3)

Comment: Currently new daemon instance is always created on debugging.There is related discussion on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228584

Comment: @y.bedrov thank you! So the solution is to disable "Enable Gradle script debugging" in run configuration. Would you mind writing an answer?

Comment: Disabling "Enable Gradle script debugging" did nothing for me. Gradle continues to spawn a new daemon every run. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-234680

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may disable "Enable Gradle script debugging"  option in run configuration. Related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228584

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround works only in 2019.3.3 (and not works in 2019.3.4 or 2020.1 Beta)

Comment: Still a problem, fix still applies (at least for me).  Ticket with the most recent activity and screenshot, on how to fix: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-242658